# creating a spashscreen and making it to stay for few seconds

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I wanted a spashscreen to be shown, it should stay a few a seconds so the user can read the contents in splash screen.

1. I have made all my .jar files into a single .jar file by adding the below code in build.xml,

   ```
   <!-- Change the value of this property to be the name of your JAR,
        minus the .jar extension. It should not have spaces.
        <property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>
   -->
   <property name="store.jar.name" value="store"/>


   <!-- don't edit below this line -->

   <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
   <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

   <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

   <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
   <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>

   <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
       <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
       <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

       <manifest>
           <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
       </manifest>
   </jar>

   <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
       <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
       excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
   </zip>

   <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
   ```

I am using netbeans. The jar file is created by right clicking on the build xml file,

Run Target -> Other Targets -> package-for-store

Any clue how to build the splash screen and hold it for a few seconds?

Thanks

Comment: I don't use Netbeans so maybe I'm missing something, but there doesn't seem to be anything in here about a splashscreen.  Perhaps you need to include your `main.class` source code?

Comment: In the manifest tag add info for your splash screen:
<attribute name="SplashScreen-Image" value="path/Splash_Image.jpg"/>
Had the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create your self a `JWindow` (it's already undecorated).
2. Pass to this window, the "main" class that needs to be loaded after the window is closed..
3. Add what ever it is you want to display to.
4. Use a `javax.swing.Timer` to "wait" a given period of time.  When the timer triggers, close the window and use the "main" class reference to load the rest of the application.

**Additional...**

You could also take a look at [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)